# check if the file exists, if not, create

Tags: php, xml, file, domdocument

how do i check using php dom, if an xml file exists, and if not create it.

```
<?php
    header("Location: index.php");

    $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmldoc->load('sample.xml');
    $newAct = $_POST['activity'];

    $root = $xmldoc->firstChild;
    $newElement = $xmldoc->createElement('activity');
    $root->appendChild($newElement);
    $newText = $xmldoc->createTextNode($newAct);
    $newElement->appendChild($newText);
    $xmldoc->save('sample.xml');

?>
```

right now, since it doesn't exists, it gives me this error:

```
DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't do that with dom, check it yourself:

```
if(file_exists('sample.xml')){
    $xmldoc->load('sample.xml');
} else {
    $xmldoc->loadXML('<root/>');//or any other rootnode name which strikes your fancy.
}
```

The saving to file would be done automatically with the `$xmldoc->save();` further on.

Comment: You might also want to check that the path points to a file (`is_file()`), that the file is readable (if it exists, `is_readable()`) and is writeable (`is_writable()`).

Comment: @salathe: indeed, those would be the next hurdles one would employ when writing proper code capable of recognizing & reporting error conditions.

Answer (score 2):

using `file_exists('sample.xml')`

Comment: Let me just state that `file_exists()` function doesn't always work (i.e. if you need to touch file on **remote server**). In this case you can use:
`if(@fopen('http://www.somedomain.com/sample.xml', 'r')) //do something;`
This function is a bit slower than `file_exists()` but works like a charm in every scenario.
I ran into this problem just now and wanted to share my findings.

Answer (score 0):

load function returns true and false. Try to use this code:

```
...
$res = $xmldoc->load('sample.xml');
if ($res === FALSE)
{
     /// not exists
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php